# Turning Youtube audio to a number

Tags: javascript, audio, youtube

I'm trying to find a way to make a visualiser in javascript so I need to be able to get the audio output level from a youtube video and turn it into some sortof percentage or number. If anybody could help  that would be great.

Comment: Explain as what you tried till.. if possible pls post fiddle

Comment: @AntoKing Dont really have a fiddle but was wondering if you could get the audio output from a playing youtube video

Comment: Where is the video playing? Are you writing an extension? Or in an IFrame embed?

Comment: I'm making a bookmarklet that makes the background of the page change color to the video thats playing.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this will only work with the HTML5 player.

You can create an [AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext) object:

```
context = new AudioContext()
```

and connect it to the YouTube video element:

```
src = context.createMediaElementSource($('#movie_player video'))
```

You can then use a [ScriptProcessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext.createScriptProcessor) to process the playing audio in real-time. The example on the Mozilla documentation page seems to provide a good base you can build on.

Comment: I wanted to use a loop to continuousy get the audio from the output of the video, not the volume slider level.

Comment: Changed the answer to reflect that. Maybe you should remove the word "level" from your question to clarify.

Comment: As soon as I attach the AudioContext to the video the video stops and wont play anymore. Not sure how to fix that...